# Using \typeout behaviour different with \newtoks vs. \def

Tags: expansion, debugging, token-lists

I feel as I really should know this, but sadly I don't.  Why is the output of  `\typeout{\the\myToken}` not the same as having it printed in the PDF as `\the\myToken`.  No problem with a `\def`, just with something declared via `\newtoks`.

The PDF shows:

[image]

but the console shows

> DefaultValue=1-9
>
> MyToken=\DefaultValue

Expansion issue? Well, that is what I thought, but then `\expandafter\typeout{\the\myToken}` should have worked?

### Questions:

- Why is this happening?
- How do I define a `\MyTypeout{}` (or preferably *redefine* `\typeout{}`) macro so that the actual current expanded value is output in the console the same was it would be displayed in the PDF.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\myToken

\edef\CurrentValue{1-9}
\edef\DefaultValue{\CurrentValue}
\myToken={\DefaultValue}

\begin{document}
\typeout{DefaultValue=\DefaultValue}  DefaultValue=\DefaultValue

\typeout{MyToken=\the\myToken}        MyToken=\the\myToken
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In typesetting context, the expression `\the\myToken` is fully expanded and typeset in TeX's stomach. Thus the expected result is `1-9`.

Macro `\typeout` is defined in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\typeout#1{%
  \begingroup
    \set@display@protect
    \immediate\write\@unused{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

In this context (`\immediate\write`) the expression `\the<token register>` is expanded once, but the contents of the token register is not expanded further.

From "The TeXbook", "Chapter 20: Definitions (aka Macros)":

> Expanded definitions that are made with `\edef` or `\xdef` continue to
>   expand tokens until only unexpandable tokens remain, except that token
>   lists produced by `\the` are not expanded further.

`\immediate\write` is not `\edef` or `\xdef`, thus we also need:

> TeX's primitive commands `\mark{...}`, `\message{...}`,
>   `\errmessage{...}`, `\special{...}`, and `\write<number>{...}` all
>   expand the token lists in braces almost exactly as `\edef` and `\xdef`
>   do. However, a macro parameter character like `#` should not be
>   duplicated in such commands; [...]

Example:

```
\edef\x{\the\myToken}
\show\x
> \x=macro:
->\DefaultValue .

\edef\x{\x}
\show\x
> \x=macro:
->1-9.
```

Thus you need to trigger the expansion twice to get the contents of the token register expanded.

Token register can be used to simulate eTeX's `\unexpanded` (however the construct will be non-expandable, `\unexpanded` is expandable). For example, this is used in `\g@addto@macro` (`latex.ltx`) that adds some tokens in the second argument to the macro in the first argument:

```
\toksdef\toks@=0
\long\def\g@addto@macro#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \toks@\expandafter{#1#2}%
    \xdef#1{\the\toks@}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Macro `#1` is expanded once and the result is put into a token register with the additional
tokens in `#2`. The following `\xdef` defines the macro with its original definition text with the tokens in `#2` appended.

### Expansion of token register inside `\typeout`

The contents of a token register looses their non-expandable behavior if it is touched twice:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\exptok}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\the#1}%
}
\makeatother

\typeout{\exptok\myToken}
```

Macro `\typeout` should not be redefined, the contents of token registers can contain stuff that breaks, if it would expanded (undefined commands, endless recursion, ...).
Also it would disturb the usages of `\typeout` for other, is the tokens where suddenly expanded.

Comment: Thanks. So is there a good way to change this behaviour? It seems that `\makeatletter
\def\typeout#1{%
  \begingroup
 \edef\ExpandedOutput{#1}
    \set@display@protect
    \immediate\write\@unused{\ExpandedOutput}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother` seems to do what I desire, but is there a reason I should not do that?

Comment: @PeterGrill I wouldn't redefine a kernel command; in any case, use `\protected@edef` and not `\edef`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Example added, how the token register can be expanded inside `\typeout`.