# printing the value of a boolean to terminal without stopping latex

Tags: latex3, expl3

I'm trying to debug some LaTeX3 code.  To do so  I would like to write the value of an internally generated boolean to the terminal, but I don't want to stop the work-flow of the LaTeX run.

For the sake of explanation, let's say the boolean is called

```
\l__my_private_boolean_bool
```

I don't want to do the following:

```
\bool_show:N \l__my_private_boolean_bool
```

because that stops everything.

Instead, I would like to do something like the following:

```
\msg_term:x { Boolean~value~is:~~\use:c {l__my_private_boolean_bool}}
```

But what gets sent to the terminal is

```
Boolean value is: \__my_private_boolean_bool
```

I was expecting (and hoping) to see

```
Boolean value is:  false
```

or

```
Boolean value is:  true
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I've also tried:

```
\msg_term:x { Boolean~value~is:~~\cs_meaning:c {l__my_private_boolean_bool}}
```

But then I get a cryptic

```
\char"0
```

printed to the screen.

> MWE

This example does what I want, but what I would like to know is whether there is already a native LaTeX3 command that achieves the same thing as my `\__ace_show_bool:N`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l__ace_test_bool
\cs_new:Npn \__ace_show_bool:N #1 {
    \bool_if:nTF { #1 }
        { true }{ false }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testsetbool}{ m }{
    \str_if_eq:nnTF {true}{#1}
        {
            \bool_gset_true:N \l__ace_test_bool
        }
        {
            \bool_gset_false:N \l__ace_test_bool
        }
    \msg_term:x { Boolean~is:~~\__ace_show_bool:N \l__ace_test_bool }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

First \testsetbool{true}

Second \testsetbool{false}

Third \testsetbool{true}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Related Question: [Using \typeout behaviour different with \newtoks vs. \def](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84736/using-typeout-behaviour-different-with-newtoks-vs-def).

Comment: @PeterGrill.  Thanks for the link.  But, I want to know how to do this in LaTeX3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LaTeX3's `bool` data type is not implemented by simply storing `true` or `false` in a macro, and so you can't simple insert the variable name and expect it to print. Indeed, over time the underlying implementation has changed since there are alternative approaches with subtly-different benefits/issues. As such, the only 'correct' way to use them is in conditionals: inside `\bool_show:N` that is exactly what happens. So if you want to print the value of a `bool`, or store it inside some other variable, you need a conditional

```
\bool_if:NTF \l_my_bool
  { TRUE }
  { FALSE }
```